# Salesforce Connected App

Tags: connected-apps

I have a question about connected app in salesforce. I investigated how connected app is authenticate via OAuth 2.0 and found that when OAuth settings are enabled on SF side it issues a client id and client secret. When this setting become disabled it is not possible to see client id and client secret. But you still can use it to login to SF from connected app and you can upload the package to other org and it still works. The same thing about scope. Could anyone explain if the client id will expire in some period of time or when it issued once it remains the same?

Answer (score 1):

Once your application is registered, SFDC issue "client credentials" in the form of a client ID and client secret. The Client ID and Client Secret are used to authenticate the identity of the application to the SFDC when the application requests to access API. Once Client ID and Client Secret verified system return a access_token as response which comes with expire time.

So in simple term Client_ID and Client Secret don't expire only access_token expire with the time.

Comment: And if 'Enable OAuth settings is unchecked'?